# Querying for associations which include all items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 associations:

```
Invoice
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :items, through: :invoice_items

InvoiceItem
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :item 

Item
  has_many :invoice_items
  has_many :invoices, through: :invoice_items
```

I am to write a report that selects all invoices which have InvoiceItem of both item_id 1 and item_id 2

I can do this with Ruby just fine.

```
invoices = Invoice.joins(:invoice_items).where(item_id: [1, 2])
invoices.each do |invoice|
  if ([1,2] - invoice_items.pluck(:item_id).uniq).empty?
    @real_invoices << invoice 
  end 
end
```

However with the millions of records, this isn't exactly feasible.

I have tried:

```
Invoice.joins(:invoice_items).having('COUNT(CASE WHEN invoice_items.item_id IN (?) THEN 1 END) = ?',[1,2], [1,2].length).group(:id)
```

But this doesn't produce the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a subquery here. This could be done as follows:
1) Select `invoice_items.invoice_id` where `invoice_items.item_id` is 1
2) Select `invoice_items.invoice_id` where `invoice_items.item_id` is 2
3) Intersect the result of these two queries to get invoice IDs which are common to both
4) Fetch invoices using these IDs

```
Invoice.where("
    invoices.id IN
      (
        SELECT invoice_items.invoice_id
        FROM invoice_items
        WHERE invoice_items.item_id = 1

        INTERSECT

        SELECT invoice_items.invoice_id
        FROM invoice_items
        WHERE invoice_items.item_id = 2
      )
")
```

This would prevent a join by using information from the `invoice_items` relation, but would make multiple subqueries. Your call to the DB from the application would be a single one though.